# Python 3.4 и MySQL. Почему запрос выполняется с ошибкой?

Tags: mysql, python

Через MySQL коннектор пытаюсь сделать запрос к БД

```
query = ("SELECT * FROM taxe_client WHERE client_token = %s")
print (clientToken)
cursor.execute(query, (clientToken))
# смотрим количество возвращенных строк, если больше 0, то значит токен клиента в бд присутствует
result = cursor.fetchall()
colRows = len(result)
if colRows > 0:
    # клиент в базе есть, берем данные
    for row in result:
        idClient = row[0]
        print(idClient)
```

Во время выполнения возникает исключение:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

Если переписать запрос в виде

```
query = ("SELECT * FROM taxe_client WHERE client_token = '%s'")
```

то ошибка исчезает, хотя такой токен в базе есть.
Если снова переписать запрос с явным указанием токена:

```
query = ("SELECT * FROM taxe_client WHERE client_token = '894d723f2daf0fb0fa99881152663691'")
```

то idClient отображается. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

передавайте аргументы в кортеже:

в 3 строке добавьте ",":

```
cursor.execute(query, (clientToken,))
```